# how to iterate arraylist in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, arraylist, pdo

**What my code does:**
                 I am returning   arraylist from a php method -->method name:- getSubjectInfo().
And in my (Index.php) page i am getting this arraylist values in a $results variable. *Here i am stuck how to iterate the arraylist values in the index.php page?.*

**My Problem:** How to iterate the arraylist ($results) in my index.php page? Please see my below mention code

i have used `$results = $sub_info->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`   in my method for  generating list.

### index.php

```
        <?php
            include_once '../../classes/conn/connection.php';
            include_once '../../classes/setups/Subdetails_setup.php'; 
            $con = new connection(); 
            $info = new Subdetails_setup($con); 
            $results = $info->getSubjectInfo();     
            echo $results; //this is returning a list of objects. My problem is how can i iterate these values
        ?>
```

and i tried like this   `echo  (each($results));` but this is printing my values in a single line 
         like this:- `Subject Name   1     FIction1Non FIction2`

**& My  Subdetails_setup.php Class  is having method getSubjectInfo()**  :-

```
   function getSubjectInfo()
 { 
    $sub_info = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM subjectdetails");
    $sub_info->execute();

    $results = $sub_info->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    foreach ($results as $key)
        { 
           echo $key->subject_name; 
            echo $key->subject_id; 
        }
    // Return the result array
        return $results;
   }
```

Please help me for this.
-Ashutosh

Comment: If you post code here on the site and you want to benefit answers to your question, I highly suggest you properly indent the code-fragments so those are more easy to read. Right now, just looking at your question, users might not feel really motivated because it is hard to read. Also it is not clear what you ask for. You say what does not work for you, however it's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: must be you are looking to iterate returned results, so this should look like foreach ($results as $value){echo $value->subject_name}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code in your **Subdetails_setup.php** needs to be removed, and put on the **index.php**. You don't need it in subdetails, just return the result.

```
    foreach ($results as $key)
    { 
       echo $key->subject_name; 
       echo $key->subject_id; 
    }
```

If you want to check if it's all working, change your **index.php** and add this line:

```
    $results = $info->getSubjectInfo();
    var_dump($results);
```

Now that **var_dump()** works, replace the line with the earlier code, modified to show a table:

```
    foreach ($results as $key)
    { 
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$key->subject_name."</td>"; 
       echo "<td>"$key->subject_id."</td>"; 
       echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: yes it is working fine. Now it is returning a arraylist. But again my problem is how can i iterate this arraylist and show db table columns in a <td>$subjectname</td> format.

Comment: thanks. in my above (index.php)code i just added -> foreach ($results as $value){echo $value->subject_name}; And this woks fine. And i tried your code also ,even ur code works fine. I do not know which is the best way to iterate list. Which one u will suggest for me?

Comment: It doesn't matter, it's just a question of style and whichever suits you best.